# jQuery posts version in AJAX call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a simple script that gets the value of a textarea and posts this via AJAX. If I post "??" I get strange values. If I log out the value it retrieves before posting it all is correct. But the POST data my script receives includes the jQuery version number. My code and results are are below. Should I be escaping this somehow ?

```
var value = $("#textarea").val();

$.ajax({
        url:'index.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:'text='+value,
        dataType:'JSON',
        success:function(data){}
    });
```

My post data comes through as "jQuery17106460378167700797_1345234676316" for the value of text.

Comment: scoping issue? did you try with `data:'text='+$("#textarea").val(),`

Comment: This looks to me like a jsonp callback, but you didnt defined dataType as jsonp, I'll try to recreate

Comment: Changed data:'text='+value to data: {text :  value} and works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a POST request, not GET, and should be:

```
var value = $("#textarea").val();

$.ajax({
    url:'index.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: {text :  value}, //object
    dataType:'JSON',
    success:function(data){

    }
});
```

PHP

```
$value = $_POST['text'];
```

Also, setting the dataType to JSON evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner, any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. This means any malformed JSON, and your ajax call will fail.

Comment: actually object gets serialized into url query same as with GET method, problem is that when using serialized string $.ajax call replaces ?? with jQuery version. Dont know if this is intended by jQuery team or a bug, but I have tired it with ??? and it left last ? intact, and with ???? it gave me last two ? intact and so on.

Comment: @IvanHušnjak - that is correct, you can use a string or a map that will be converted into a string, but for POST it uses a different technique of sending the data as it can't be appended to the URL, so it's sent as UTF8 form data, and using a map is usually easier to understand and simpler when using variables etc. It could also just be the returned JSON not being up to standards, I'll add that to my answer !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure when you are executing the script, is it on button press?

If not, you will need to wrap it so that it runs only after DOM had completed loading:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var value = $("#textarea").val();
    $.ajax({
            url:'index.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:'text='+value,
            dataType:'JSON',
            success:function(data){}
        });
});
```